# An Array of markers does not display on mapview React native (Expo)

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-maps

Array of markers do not display on Mapview(Expo). would need help on it please

Have used the index and lattitude with Date.now as key all still not working.
Have tried using a fixed longitude and latitude on map to know whether its from the coordinates provided but it still doesnt show up

data being passed

```
const nearByDrivers = [
    {
        "coordinate": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -0.16791,
                5.67744
            ]
        },
        "online": true,
        "socketId": "",
        "_id": "5c09433ea3c5ce10b03e8e63",
        "driverId": "5c09433ea3c5ce10b03e8e62",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "coordinate": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -0.14923,
                5.646106
            ]
        },
        "online": true,
        "socketId": "",
        "_id": "5c094ac7d92c8f2bd88d6014",
        "driverId": "5c094ac6d92c8f2bd88d6013",
        "__v": 0
    }
]``
```

Ive looked at the other docs at stackoverflow but doent know why it doestnt render i might be missing something

```
import React from "react";
import { View } from "native-base";
import { MapView } from "expo";
import styles from "./MapTrackStyles.js";

export const MapTrack = ({
region,
nearByDrivers,
}) => {

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <MapView
      provider={MapView.PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
      style={styles.map}
      region={region}
    >
      {nearByDrivers.map((item, index) => {
        <MapView.Marker
          key={index}
          coordinate={{
            //latitude: marker.coordinate.coordinates[1],
            //longitude: marker.coordinate.coordinates[0]
            latitude: 5.67744,
            longitude: -0.16791,
          }}
          pinColor="green"
        />
      })
      }
    </MapView>
  </View>
);
};

export default MapTrack;
```

Comment: It's not easy to understand, but can I show you the whole code?

Comment: yes please you can

Comment: please share your package.json file, what expo SDK are you using?